# Утечка памяти QThread

Tags: qt

При создании большого количества потоков в цикле получаю утечку памяти. Внутри потока ничего не создаю, просто вывод строки в cout

```
for (int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
{
    bool res;
    MyThread* thread = new MyThread();
    QObject::connect (thread, SIGNAL (finished ()), thread, SLOT (deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
}
```

Деструктор вызывается, но потребляемая память только растёт.

Код, выполняющийся в потоке:

```
void MyThread::run()
{
    cout << "test " << endl;
    // do some work
    emit finished();
}
```

Comment: Покажите класс MyThread. Может вы сигнал finished не испускаете

Comment: void MyThread::run()
{
    cout << "test " << endl;
    emit finished();
}

Comment: У вас проблема с 'deleteLater()'. Нужно четко понимать когда будет удаление. Для этого лучше обратится к документации (я и сам толком не разобрался). По этому попробуйте просто создать отдельный слот и там использовать обычный 'delete'. Также можете попробовать лямбда функцию (у меня что-то похожее на ваше и там 'deleteLater()' точно срабатывает).

Comment: Проблема в том, что слот destroyed потока отрабатывает. Ладно, попробую через лямбды

Answer (score 0):

Не следует наследоваться от QThread. Наследуйте от QObject (пусть будет worker), создавайте обычный QThread и перемещайте объект в него.

```
void QObject::moveToThread(QThread *targetThread)
```

Тогда все слоты, вызванные сигналами, будут обработаны отдельным потоком. Удалять объект можно отправив сигнал в его слот deleteLater() как-то так

```
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finish()), thread, SLOT(quit()))
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()))
```

Когда worker испустит сигнал finish(), поток остановится и вызовет деструктор worker.